# Find the average salary of workers born in June? Which statement should I use in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my employee data:

[image]

The question is how to get the average salary of employees born in June?

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple enough:

```
SELECT AVG(Salary)
FROM dbo.YourEmployees
WHERE MONTH(Birthdate) = 6;
```

I'm not fluent in Vietnamese - so I couldn't figure out which column means what - that's up to you to do the translation of the column names here.....

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(LUONG)
 FROM my_employee_data
 WHERE MONTH(NGAYSINH)=6
```

As I don't know the language, above is assumption how it can look